# Why just one lib doesn't work in MANIFEST.MF file?

Tags: java, manifest, xmlbeans

I'm facing a problem when I run my app with the dependencies declared in the manifest.mf file.
The manifest is OK, and the problem occurs only with a specific lib generated by [Apache XML Beans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) using ANT.

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: my_project
Implementation-Version: 0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: note
Class-Path: ALL_LIBS
Main-Class: myPackage.MainClass
Implementation-Vendor: My Company
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_31
Specification-Version: 3.4.2
```

An approach I've tried and works is run it by the following command:
"JAVA_HOME\bin\java.exe" -cp "main.jar;../lib/*" myPackage.MainClass

But I can't do it in production, so, anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue in two steps.

First I removed all ANT scripts (apparently it is not a good practice to generate in a maven project).

Second I added the plugin to xmlbeans like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now everything is working pretty well!